# servlets couldnt accessible from webapplication in linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat6

I have deployed Myapplication.war in tomcat webapps directory.

now i have, index.jsp in $CATALINAHOME/webapps/Myapplication and process.class in $CATALINAHOME/webapps/Myapplication/WEB-INF/classes.

When index.jsp post some variables to process, http://x.x.x.x:8080/Myapplication/process

Im getting below err,

type Status report
message /Myapplication/process
description The requested resource is not available..

if i convert the process file from java class to jsp, im able to post from index.jsp to process.jsp.

How can i achieve this? any other settings i need to do here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of tomcat? Is `process` a servlet? Have you modified `web.xml`?

Comment: its tomcat6. yes, process is a servlet. i havent updated web.xml [ not sure what settings need to done there ]

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to declare your servlet in `web.xml` otherwise Tomcat won't know which class to associate with which path:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>processServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>process</servlet-class>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>processServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/process</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

See also the [tomcat sample deployment descriptor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/web.xml.txt)

A couple of minor niggles:

- As per Java class naming, classes should start with an uppercase character, so it would be `Process` and `Process.java`.
- Usually it makes more sense to put java classes into a package.

Comment: when i add above snippets in web.xml alsong with below,  <web-app><welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app> Now, im not able to access index.jsp itself...